# Веса для ключевых фраз в тексте

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, nlp, spacy

Есть статья, мне в ней нужно выделить ключевые фразы по паттерну и определить их веса.
Ключевые фразы я выделил.Привожу код

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load('ru_core_news_lg')

text = '''Тут текст статьи'''
doc = nlp(text)
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{"POS": "ADJ"}, {"POS": "NOUN"}]
matcher.add("AdjNoun", [pattern])
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(span)
```

Ключевые фразы получил. Как теперь определить их веса, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Какие веса, для чего веса? Могу только предположить, что имелось в виду преобразование `TF-IDF`, так, или нет?

Comment: Да, именно TF IDF

Comment: Изучайте библиотеку sklearn, если ещё не начали https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html). Пример из документации:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> corpus = [
...     'This is the first document.',
...     'This document is the second document.',
...     'And this is the third one.',
...     'Is this the first document?',
... ]
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
>>> print(X.shape)
(4, 9)
```